# Creating a .txt file from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `.txt` file like this:

```
ID - NAME - LASTNAME - USER - PASSWORD

0001 - Oliver - Jackson - olson - pass123

0002 - Samuel - Depp - samuel - pass321
```

Then, I created a dictionary from the .txt file:

```
{'0001': ['Oliver', 'Jackson', 'olson', 'pass123'], '0002': ['Samuel', 'Depp', 'samuel', 'pass321']}
```

Now, if someone wants to change one of the values inside the dictionary it's easy, but I need to overwrite the .txt file with such new values, something like this (no luck until now):

```
{'0001': ['Oliver', 'Jackson', 'newlog01', 'newpass01'], '0002': ['Samuel', 'Depp', 'samuel', 'pass321']}

0001 - Oliver - Jackson - newlog01 - newpass01

.

.

.
```

Thanks

Comment: you could just change the string in the file and run your program again to create the dictionary

Comment: Use the native Python module `json`. No need for wasteful to and from JSON conversion.

Comment: Your data structure is backwards. Instead of creating a `dict` that points to `list`s, you should make a `list` that holds `dict`s: `[{'NAME':'Oliver', 'LASTNAME':'Jackson', 'USER':'olson', 'PASSWORD':'pass123'}, {next user}, {etc.}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will work for your current system, but it's recommended you don't store this data in your own custom format. You should simply use the build in `json` library.

```
import json

input = '{\"0001\": [\"Oliver\", \"Jackson\", \"newlog01\", \"newpass01\"], \"0002\": [\"Samuel\", \"Depp\", \"samuel\", \"pass321\"]}'

data = dict()

try:
    data = json.loads(input)
except ValueError as e:
    print e

print 'ID - NAME - LASTNAME - USER - PASSWORD'
for key in sorted(data.keys()):
    print ' - '.join([key] + data[key])
```

Output:

```
ID - NAME - LASTNAME - USER - PASSWORD
0001 - Oliver - Jackson - newlog01 - newpass01
0002 - Samuel - Depp - samuel - pass321
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to replace the entire file with the new contents

```py
def read_file(filename):
    data = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as fhd:
        for line in fhd:
            tokens = [token.strip() for token in line.split('-')]
            data[tokens[0]] = tokens[1:]
    return data


def write_file(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as fhd:
        for key in sorted(data.keys()):
            fhd.write('{} - {}\n'.format(key, ' - '.join(data[key])))
```

And use it as:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = 'test.dat'
    data = read_file(filename)
    data['0001'][1] = 'changed'
    write_file(filename, data)
```

There is no way around it. Data in disk is stored serially.

Comment: You don't have to replace the entire file.  You can use `seek()`, and `write()` if you're careful.

Comment: You'll have to make sure that the replacement string has the same size as the string being replaced.And I see your point, you could hack your way through a solution by making each field have a reserved amount of bytes available.

Answer (score 0):

One quick way to do this is just create a serialization function that given one of your specially formatted dictionaries, will return it as a string encoded in your custom format.  Then just write that out to the original file and you're golden.

e.g.

```
import os

def encode(data):
    header = "ID - NAME - LASTNAME - USER - PASSWORD"
    lines = [' - '.join([key] + values) for (key, values) in data.iteritems()]
    return (os.linesep+os.linesep).join([header] + lines)
```

Then you can write it back out again with something like:

```
with open('data.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(encode(d) + os.linesep)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can use the `json` library , it's very good for your project.
if you don't want to use `json` file and you need to change some datas from txt file :

```
import os 
new_txtfile=open("newfile.txt","w")
def get_the_datas_from_your_txtfile():
    #on this function you can do change as you want with dictionary
    # and now whrite the new dictionary to new_txtfile 
get_the_datas_from_your_txtfile()
your_txtfile.close()
new_txtfile.close() #her closing files 

os.remove("your_txtfile.txr")
os.renames("new_txtfile.txt","your_txtfile.txt")
#on thir we have removed the old file and changed the
#new files name to old files name
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it about as tight as possible.

```
d_map = {'0001': ['Oliver', 'Jackson', 'olson', 'pass123'], '0002': ['Samuel', 'Depp', 'samuel', 'pass321']}
rv_str = ''
for key in d_map.keys():
    rv_str += key + ' - ' + ' - '.join(d_map[key]) + '\n'
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file_d:
    file_d.write(rv_str)
```